# Vertical Scrollbar using CSS Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a vertical scrollbar as shown in [this site](https://we3.jam3.com/designer).

[image: Screenshot.png]

Can someone please guide me on how this can be done? Any sample code would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably look at some of these scroll libraries to give you nice effects from the page:

- http://scrollmagic.io/
- https://scrollrevealjs.org/
- https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

And for that Vertical Navigation:

- https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-fixed-navigation/
- https://codepen.io/janmez/pen/gryoKG

  ```
  Vertical Navigation Scroll Effect
  ```
- http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your example isn't exactly a scrollbar. It has some of the behaviors that a scrollbar have, but you can't use it to navigate, and it's not replacing the default scroll bar, at least not at the code.

Currently, only Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, others) [can have their scrollbar styled](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar), and IE can be partially styled.

That example of yours was made "from scratch", by using JavaScript to make HTML elements behave like a scrollbar.

[Jquery custom scrollbar](https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar) is a Jquery plugin that really helps you create custom scrollbars, but probably doesn't provide enough functionalities to make such a complex scrollbar as of the example you gave.